# Best algorithm to determine if an undirected graph is a tree

Tags: graph-algorithm

What is the time complexity of the Best algorithm to determine if an undirected graph  is a tree??

can we say Big-oh(n) , with n vertices??

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is O(n). With a depth-first search in a directed graph has 3 types of non-tree edges - cross, back and forward.

For an undirected case, the only kind of non-tree edge is a back edge. So, you just need to search for back edges.

In short, choose a starting vertex. Traverse and keep checking if the edge encountered is a back edge. If you find n-1 tree edges without finding back-edges and then, run out of edges, you're gold.

(Just to clarify - a `back edge` is one where the vertex at the other end has already been encountered - and because of the properties of undirected graphs, the vertex at the other end would be an ancestor of the present node in the tree that is being constructed.)

Comment: thnx.. can we also do it using BFS in O(n) time

Comment: You can, but BFS could be slower because it won't find cycles as fast.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is O(n).

Pick a starting node, and perform depth first traversal. If you visit a node more than once, it isn't a tree.

Comment: Thnx anthony...can we also do it using BFS with O(n) time

Comment: Yes, but depth-first is better because it will find cycles faster.

Comment: Also verify that all nodes are visited, otherwise the graph could be a forest.