# Determine if undirected graph is connected

Tags: graph, depth-first-search

I came across this posting from a while back:

[Best algorithm to determine if an undirected graph is a tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367485/best-algorithm-to-determine-if-an-undirected-graph-is-a-tree)

It says that to determine if an undirected graph is a tree, you just have to check if it has a cycle.  However, don't you have to make sure the graph is connected? I was taught that a tree is connected *and* acyclic.  How is checking only for acyclicity sufficient?

Thanks.

Comment: for program implementation [check this](http://www.msccomputerscience.com/2014/04/wap-to-check-whether-graph-is-connected.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. If the graph is acyclic, then it's a forest. In addition, if it only has one component, then it's a tree.

What the algorithm mentioned does is look for back edges. If it finds one, then the graph is not a tree. If it doesn't find one and the algorithm visited n-1 edges before running out of edges, then it IS a tree, because having visited n-1 edges means that the graph is indeed connected (a tree with n vertices has n-1 edges). If the algorithm ran out of edges but didn't reach n-1 visited edges, then it means the graph is not connected, hence it is not a tree.

Comment: But where is it keeping track of the number of edges it has visited?