# Determining whether or not a directed or undirected graph is a tree

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree

I would like to know of a fast algorithm to determine if a directed or undirected graph is a tree.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367485/best-algorithm-to-determine-if-an-undirected-graph-is-a-tree) post seems to deal with it, but it is not very clear; according to this link, if the graph is acyclic, then it is a tree. But if you consider the directed and undirected graphs below: in my opinion, only graphs 1 and 4 are trees. I suppose 3 is neither cyclic, nor a tree.

[image]

What needs to be checked to see if a directed or undirected graph is a tree or not, in an efficient way?  And taking it one step ahead: if a tree exists then is it a binary tree or not?

Comment: A quick note, the linked question *does* deal with only the undirected case. My understanding is that you wanted to deal with the directed case? In the directed case, there are also other cases to worry about (is `A -> B <- C` a tree?).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

For a directed graph:

- Find the vertex with no incoming edges (if there is more than one or no such vertex, fail).
- Do a [breadth-first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) from that vertex. If you encounter an already visited vertex, it's not a tree.
- If you're done and there are unexplored vertices, it's not a tree - the graph is not connected.
- Otherwise, it's a tree.
- To check for a binary tree, additionally check if each vertex has at most 2 outgoing edges.

For an undirected graph:

- Check for a cycle with a simple depth-first search (starting from any vertex) - ["If an unexplored edge leads to a node visited before, then the graph contains a cycle."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526331/cycles-in-an-undirected-graph.) If there's a cycle, it's not a tree.
- If the above process leaves some vertices unexplored, it's not a tree, because it's not connected.
- Otherwise, it's a tree.
- To check for a binary tree, if the graph has more than one vertex, additionally check that all vertices have 1-3 edges (1 to the parent and 2 to the children).

  Checking for the root, i.e. whether one vertex contains 1-2 edges, is not necessary as there *has to* be vertices with 1-2 edges in an acyclic connected undirected graph.

  Note that identifying the root is not generically possible (it may be possible in special cases) as, in many undirected graphs, more than one of the nodes can be made the root if we were to make it a binary tree.

Comment: regarding point 1 : I could have a private `OutgoingEdge` array field in the Vertex class, such that when each edge is added to graph, I can update this field. for every vertex, I check if this array length is > 1. if it is, it is not a tree..

Comment: regarding point 2: this is nothing but cycle detection right? any specific reason for BFS over DFS

Comment: regarding point 3: I can get this information from my `outgoingEdge` array field if its length is <=2

Comment: as you mention checking for the root in undirected acyclic connected graph is not essential, because there are possible of multiple nodes that could act as roots?

Comment: `#1` Makes sense, this is typically how [adjacency lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) work, which is mostly used in graph implementations. `#2` Yes, I believe you can also use DFS, no particular reason for picking BFS. `#3` Yes. Yes, in many cases multiple nodes could act as the root.

Comment: One other point is that we should consider if graph is connected or not. If it is not connected, even having n - 1 edges and no cycle, still does not necessarily mean that graph is a tree and it can be a forest. Just wanted to mention that sometimes we may need to check the number of connected components in graph to be sure that graph is connected.

Comment: @Pedram: Should correct myself, ....."even having no cycle, still does not necessarily mean that graph is a tree and it can be a forest....."

Comment: @Pedram Edited.

Comment: For directed graph 1: I would say "No incoming edges"; since the trivial tree with only one node has no edges at all. "Only outgoing edges" is less clear for that case.

Answer (score 0):

If an undirected given graph is a tree:

- the graph is connected
- the number of edges equals the number of nodes - 1.

Answer (score 0):

I can add that, in case of oriented graph where each node has at most one parent, if you already know that there is only one root, instead of implementing DFS (Depth First Search) you can:

1. find that specific root,
2. write a recursion that:
   -saves all visited nodes,
   -returns when it reach a leaf (node with no children),
   -when it reach a node that is not a leaf iterate through all children of
   that node (recursively).

If it's connected (all nodes have been visited) and has #(edges) = #(nodes) - 1 then its a tree
If every node is at most 3-valent, then it's a binary tree.

If visited nodes are all nodes of a graph, then it is connected. If it's connected then

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

An undirected graph is a tree when the following two conditions are true:

1. The graph is a connected graph.
2. The graph does not have a cycle.

A directed graph is a tree when the following three conditions are true:

1. The graph is a connected graph.
2. The graph does not have a cycle.
3. Each node except root should have exactly one parent.