# Guava Graph package: Method for testing if a undirected graph is a tree

Tags: java, tree, guava, graph-theory

I want to write a function that tests if a undirected Graph is a tree.
So far, I'm using this:

```
Function<Graph<Integer>, Double> targetFunction = g -> {
    boolean isConnected = Graphs.reachableNodes(g, g.nodes().iterator().next()).equals(g.nodes());
    return isConnected && Graphs.hasCycle(g);
};
```

Is there already an implementation for this method in Guava (didn't find one) and if no, can this be improved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation has two problems.

- `g.nodes().iterator().next()` returns the first node - `n1` in the graph. Assume the graph is a tree, `n1` might not be the root of the tree. So its reachable nodes is a subset of all nodes.
- `hasCycle` only detect back edges, but not forward edges or cross edges. Check [the answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/11125/91791) to find out the difference.

I cannot find a direct solution from guava graph api. It only provides basic support for graph data structure, bfs, and dfs.

This question, [Determining whether or not a directed or undirected graph is a tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20556802/5360439), shows how to implement what the algorithm you want.

Comment: Ok sorry, I should have made explicit that the graph is undirected. Your points would be valid in the directed case though. My question was more about if there was a better solution than mine.